# R - Converting formulae to character strings and vice versa

Tags: r, formula

I am a bit confused by some strange behaviour in `R`.  When you turn a formula into a character string, it automatically separates the two parts of the formula into separate elements, as follows:

```
#Convert formula to character string
FORMULA <- formula(y ~ a + b + c + d)
CHAR    <- as.character(FORMULA)
CHAR    
[1] "~"             "y"             "a + b + c + d"
```

However, when you try to convert back you don't get the original formula:

```
as.formula(CHAR)
~y
```

Why does this happen ---i.e., why doesn't `R` convert back to the formula you started with?  Is there a function (or some other simple way) to convert from the character string back to the formula?

Comment: What is the end goal? Do you want to to edit specific parts of the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `format` to go from a formula to a character string and use `as.formula` to go in the other direction:

```
FORMULA <- formula(y ~ a + b + c + d)  # from question
format(FORMULA)
## [1] "y ~ a + b + c + d"

as.formula("y ~ a + b + c + d")
## y ~ a + b + c + d
```

Also, `y ~ a + b + c + d` is already a formula.  There is no point in using `formula(...)` on something that is already a formula:

```
identical(y ~ a + b + c + d, formula(y ~ a + b + c + d))
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, you could piece the original formula back together using `paste`:

```
as.formula(paste(CHAR[2], CHAR[1], CHAR[3]))

y ~ a + b + c + d
```